# How to render Uint8List as a PdfImage in flutter?

Tags: flutter, image, dart

I have used this screenshot package:
https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot
It gives back a Uint8list but I need to print it as a pdfImage using: https://pub.dev/packages/printing. How would I do that?

The below is my printing code.

```
doc.addPage(pw.Page(
 build: (pw.Context context) {
  return pw.Center(
    child: pw.Image(_imageFile),
  ); // Center
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

First u need to convert the Unit8List to File, to convert

```dart
// add path_provider package to pubspec.yaml
  final _snapController = ScreenshotController();
  _snapController.capture().then((Uint8List? imageFile) async {
      // saving to local temp-directory
      final tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
      File _file = await File('${tempDir.path}/$_userId.png').create();
      _file.writeAsBytesSync(imageFile!);
      _snapImage = _file;
      // Now u can print this img......
   });
```

Note that, its very complicated to convert the Unit8List to File without path_provider package.